# Apache Solr 4.0 Admin UI is not working under MSIE

Tags: internet-explorer, solr

After migrating from Solr 3.6 to Solr 4.0 I found out that Sole Admin UI is not working under MSIE. Tried versions 7,8,9 - no luck. It's just totally disfunctional with dead links and a bunch of javascript errors in console. It works in Chrom & Firefox though.

Am I doing something wrong or is that a known thing? Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3876

Comment: thanks for the post - stopped me looking for the non-existent problem with my Solr setup.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [linked issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3876) Mauricio provided in the comments this was a known issue with Solr 4.0 Beta, 4.0 Release Candidates, and the initial 4.0 release.  The issue was resolved in Solr 4.1.